# How to post log in .json format to stdout in Mule?

Tags: json, logging, mule, stdout

I try to post my log to stdout. This works fine, but I have to rewrite it to .json format.

I tried to use the following:
(found the idea on [github](https://github.com/majikthys/log4j2-logstash-jsonevent-layout))

```
<Appenders>
        <Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <LogStashJSONLayout>

            <!-- Example of what you might do to add fields, warning values should be known to be json escaped strings -->
            <KeyValuePair key="application_name" value="${sys:application.name}"/>
            <KeyValuePair key="application_version" value="${sys:application.version}"/>
            <KeyValuePair key="environment_type" value="${sys:deploy_env}"/>
            <KeyValuePair key="cluster_location" value="${sys:cluster_location}"/>
            <KeyValuePair key="cluster_name" value="${sys:cluster_name}"/>
            <KeyValuePair key="hostname" value="${sys:hostname}"/>
            <KeyValuePair key="host_ip" value="${sys:host_ip}"/>

            <!--Example of using system property substitution -->
            <KeyValuePair key="application_user" value="${sys:user.name}"/>

            <!--Example of using environment property substitution  env:USERNAME on windows-->
            <KeyValuePair key="environment_user" value="${env:USER}"/> 
          </LogStashJSONLayout>
        </Console>
```

But this does not work. I see my log in stdout in plain text.
Like this:

```
please check your split expression
Processing bucket : entityresolution-datasets
Splitter returned no results. If this is not expected, please check your split expression
Processing bucket : mesos-exhibitors3bucket-10oeaynyppkt7
Splitter returned no results. If this is not expected, please check your split expression
Processing bucket : process-log
Splitter returned no results. If this is not expected, please check your split expression
Processing bucket : segmentation-datasets
Splitter returned no results. If this is not expected, please check your split expression
```

So I want to use my logstash output in the LogStashJSONLayout format and printed to console instead of posting it using socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue but eventually found a solution which fit my needs.
There's a [JSONLayout.java file on Github](https://github.com/gb96/log4j2-JSONLayout/blob/master/JSONLayout.java) that I use in my applications.

I added the file to my src/main/java folder in a package (com.example.log4j2 for example) and my log4j2 xml file looks like the following:

```
<Configuration packages="com.example.log4j2" verbose="false">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <JSONLayout>
        </JSONLayout>
   </Console>
</Appenders>
...
<Loggers>
    ...
    <AsyncRoot level="WARN">
        <AppenderRef ref="stdout" />
    </AsyncRoot>
</Loggers>
```

Let me know if this works for you as well. I made some changes to the name of the package and the @Plugin(name = ...) so I might have messed something up.